# How do I reduce the resolution of a curve circumfrence wise?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have this curve, that I want to reduce the resolution of. I know I can adjust the resolution length wise with the resolution U property, but how do I adjust it circumference wise?
[image]

[image]

edit: There is a resolution property if I set the *Bevel* to *Round*. However, I am using an object bezel. I suspect I would have to adjust the object to change the resolution, but I'm not sure how to adjust the circle curve.

[image]

Comment: Change the Bevel Depth under Geometry on the Curve Properties panel?

Comment: i'm afraid I don't see the bevel depth option? I've attached an image of my panel to my main post @JohnEason

Comment: When you use an object as profile, then of course you have to set the resolution on the object if you want to increase or decrease it. But please stop writing "bezel" instead of "bevel" like you also did in your other question, it makes it harder for people to search for bevel-related topics ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your bevel object and in the *Data panel > Shape* > change the *Resolution* value:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. It reduces the resolution length wise but not circumference wise.

Comment: @Autumn you need to select the bevel object, not the tube

Answer (score -3):

Okay, so I found a workaround by converting to a mesh and then applying a decimate modifier. It's a bit janky now but it worked.